# Subversive Connectors not available

Tags: eclipse, svn, subversive

Recently i wanted to setup a new Eclipse C++ build environment with Photon etc. So i needed to install Subversive (4.0.5) and the corresponding connectors. But the connector installation failed (he won't even find any, after the installation of subversive and the restart). Is it possible, that Polarion discontinued the SVN Connector Repository because it is simply a blank site (this should be the update site of the SVN connector: http://community.polarion.com/projects/subversive/download/eclipse/6.0/update-site/). Hope someone knows a solution.

Comment: I just ran into this myself.  Hopefully this issue will be resolved shortly but I'm somewhat pessimistic.  Apparently Polarion (the company which had been sponsoring Subversive development for many years) has been acquired by Siemens and Siemens has no interest in continuing to sponsor development.  There's [a page](https://www.eclipse.org/subversive/sponsor.php) on the Eclipse website asking someone to sponsor the project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of today when I re-tested the site is back up and running again.

Answer (score 0):

Someone have the files? We only need the connectors:

- Subversive-connectors-6.0.4.I20161211-1700.zip
- Subversive-connectors-allplatforms-6.0.4.I20161211-1700.zip

Comment: We have been hit by the same issue and have fixed it using eclipse plugin "old school" method. We have copied from a working development instance the jar files to eclipse\plugins folder and the metadata folders to eclipse\features. However you first need to install "Eclipse Subversive SVN Team Provider" before doing this.